# Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

I have written two program for my Raspberry Pi using python.

1. wait an IR signal using module pylirc in a while loop and control
   mpd (play, next, mute....)
2. display a message on a LCD (2 rows x 16 characters in each row)
   and the message can move from left to right by using a while loop
   and string function.

It both work individually.

Now, i want to combine two program in one so that i can display an update message on the LCD when an IR signal received. After surfing on the net, it seems multithreading is suitable.

However, I don't know how to communicate between the main program and the thread. Any expert has idea? A presudo code of my combined program is listed as follow:

1. create a thread to display message(e.g. IP address) the main program
2. use a while loop to wait an IR signal when an IR single received,
3. how to pass update message(e.g. play next song) to the thread????

need to create two thread to handle two tasks???

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you need a thread to display a message?

Comment: just want to display current status of the player

Comment: and the IR receive statement will wait an IR signal and will not run following statement

Comment: It would be convenient if you could provide your code.

Comment: The [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) module has lots of ways for threads to communicate. There's also the [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) module.

Comment: I second @larsmans's statements. You should really read the documentation for the ``threading`` module. It provides lots of examples of doing simple tasks like this. If you still have *specific* questions after that, then ask a new question.

Comment: [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) might also be worth a look as well depending on if the IR library plays nice with the GIL